# how do you find the name of a gpg key? (for use in maven-gpg-plugin)

Tags: maven, gnupg

This might be amateur hour here, but I've been struggling to give a key name for the purpose of gpg-signing my maven artifacts.

When i run the release:prepare goal, I get the output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ project-parent ---
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have in my ~/.m/settings.xml

```
 ...<profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <gpg.keyname>myuserid</gpg.keyname>
            <gpg.homerdir>~/.gnupg</gpg.homerdir>
            <gpg.passphrase>**********</gpg.passphrase> 
        </properties>
    </profile>...
```

but is not picking up any of my keys...

`gpg2 -k` produces:

```
sec   ****R/******4D 2014-01-16
uid                  Bob Jones (itsa me) <bob.jones@fakenameandemail.com>
ssb   ****R/******B5 2014-01-16
```

I've tried placing in `gpg.keyname` `****R`, `******4D`, `****R/******4D` and none work.

Comment: Are you running Maven under the same system user, or another? And try to replace `~/.gnupg` by the full path, expanding `~` is something your shell does, but usually no application programs.

Comment: I am running maven under my user account. the .gnupg folder is inside my user folder.

Comment: Did you try replacing `~` by your home directory path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at my spelling of `gpg.homedir` it is incorrectly spelt as `<gpg.home*r*dir>`.

Fixing this solved the problem.